# I am getting an array out of bound exception for this piece of code

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing, multidimensional-array

```
public  CompressImage(){

}


// compress image method
public static short[] compress(short image[][]){

    // get image dimensions
    int imageLength = image.length;   // row length
    int imageWidth = image[0].length; // column length    


    // convert vertical to horizontal 

    // store transposed Image
    short[][] transposeImage = new short[imageWidth][imageLength];

    // rotate by +90
    for (int i = 0; i < imageWidth; i++)
    {
          for (int j = 0; j < imageLength; j++)
          {
             short temp = image[i][j];
             transposeImage[i][j] = image[j][i];
             transposeImage[j][i] = temp;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
short temp = image[i][j];
transposeImage[i][j] = image[j][i];
transposeImage[j][i] = temp;
```

Why are you swapping here?  That doesn't make sense - `transposeImage` is a new matrix, so you don't have to do inplace editing.  This is guaranteed to break if `imageWidth != imageLength` - see if you can figure out why.

And, actually, you're not even swapping.  The three lines above are equivalent to:

```
transposeImage[i][j] = image[j][i];
transposeImage[j][i] = image[i][j];
```

The body of the nested for loop should really just be:

```
transposeImage[i][j] = image[j][i];
```

Comment: but, the new matrix should have the previous value for transposeImage[j][i], isn't it ?